# Moving youtube iframe player between divisions?

Tags: css, html, iframe, youtube, youtube-api

I am unsuccessfully trying to move an iframe containing a youtube player, by placing it into a different div in a different location on a page.  Even if i try to wrap the iframe with a div and try to move the div it does not work.

Visually, playing player not only stops playing but it reverts to showing the image of the default video that is set when the player is defined. Is this possible or is the player itself doing something to specifically prevent this from being done?

p.s. Am I the only one who is missing the old YouTube community in the google groups?

Answer (score 2):

A lot of it depends on how you're trying to go about moving the element in the DOM, but it suffices to say that, generally speaking, most methods will result in exactly what you're seeing. For example, the jQuery "appendTo" function performs a removal of the element from its parent and then an appendChild call, which triggers the YouTube player to reset to a state of -1 (loaded and ready to play). IF you try to avoid this by doing a node clone, the new player doesn't inherit any of the event bindings, and also loses its state when created.

I think you're left with trying to keep the state yourself, then; you could write a function that, when triggered, pauses the video, gets the current time, removes the video from its parent (or clones it and deletes the original, as long as you re-set up any bindings you need), and then sets the time on the new video to match where it was on the old video.